# Declaration and Instantiation of Constructor Function

Tags: typescript

How do I declare a constructor function that matches the pattern in 'myConstructor'? In the example, the compiler says when assigning the function to 'g' :  `Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type`. What should the function assigned to 'g' look like?

```
interface MyType {
    myProperty: string;
}
interface myConstructor {

    new(s: string): MyType
}


var g: myConstructor;

var g = function (s) {
    this.myProperty = s;
}

var c = new g('abc');
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically, in TypeScript, you'd write a class rather than a constructor function:

```
class MyClass implements MyType {
    myProperty: string;

    constructor(s: string) {
        this.myProperty = s;
    }
}

var c = new MyClass('abc');
```

Then the compiler will convert the class to a constructor function for browser compatibility. Using the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MyType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20myProperty%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyClass%20implements%20MyType%20%7B%0A%09myProperty%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%09constructor(s%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%09%09this.myProperty%20%3D%20s%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20new%20MyClass('abc')%3B), you can see the compiler output will be as follows (with default options):

```
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClass(s) {
        this.myProperty = s;
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
var c = new MyClass('abc');
```

Alternatively, if you really want to write a constructor function implementing an interface, have a look at the `ClockConstructor` example in the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).